# How to check if input file is empty when form submited?

Tags: go

I have the simplest form with submit button in my template.

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And some function

```
func handleUploadedForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
r.ParseMultipartForm(1000000000)
file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
defer file.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

How can i check if user submited empty form?
fmt.Println(r.PostFormValue("file")) gives me empty string even if i submit valid file.
So how can i check if input (name="file") was empty when submited?

Answer (score 0):

`header.Size` will be `0` if the uploaded file was empty.
And `err` will be non-`nil` if no file was selected. But your example code already handles that case.